# azk - how to setup a test database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec, azk

I am using azk in my development (it is a Ruby on Rails project), and azk sets up a MySQL database named `#{manifest.dir}_development` (with `manifest.dir` being the directory name where the project is).

The problem is that when I try to run the RSpec tests, it will access that same development DB, instead of a test database.

My colleagues and I have been struggling the past few hours trying to figure out how to setup a test database. How can we do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm from the azk core team and here we add a test environment by simply adding an extra pair system+db with proper settings.

It's even easier when you use extends for the test systems:

```
systems({
  example: {
    depends: ["postgres"],
    // ...
  },
  example-test: {
    extends: "example",
    depends: ["postgres-test"],
    scalable: { default: 0, limit: 1 },
    http: false,
    wait: false,
    envs: {
      // envs aren't extended by default. Add all required env vars from the original system here
      // ...
    },
  },
  postgres: {
    // ...
  },
  "postgres-test": {
    extends: "postgres",
    scalable: { default: 0, limit: 1 },
    envs: {
      // Once again, add the required env vars from postgres system here
      POSTGRES_USER: "azk",
      POSTGRES_PASS: "azk",
      POSTGRES_DB  : "#{manifest.dir}_test",
    },
  },
});
```

Make sure your `database.yml` is able to handle `DATABASE_URL` env var (we **strongly** recommend you use this one: https://gist.github.com/gullitmiranda/62082f2e47c364ef9617)

Finally, to run your tests, simply execute:

```
$ azk start postgres-test
$ azk shell example-test -- bundle exec rake test
```

This should be enough, but please let me know if you have any other issue.

Comment: Hi, I did as answered here, but it only works if the database name is the same. Otherwise, azk throws me an error:

azk: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  database "myapp_test" has disappeared from pg_database
azk: DETAIL:  Database OID 57345 now seems to belong to "myapp_pass". I have already deleted the persistent folders and reprovisioned, same error.

Comment: @shadowmaru, the test database isn't started. The commands to be run are not complete. I'll update my answer. Thank you for your feedback!